# How to send an notification 15 days after user opens the app for the first time

Tags: java, android

Hey is there anyway to send an notification  every 15 day after the first time user opens the app ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Answer is brutal: must write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the date of first run of the app using `SharedPreferences` in the `OnCreate` of the MainActivity.java.

Then you can use a Calender object to get day like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int start = sharedPref.getInt("firstRunDate", 0);
   Calender cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1;

if((dayOfMonth+15)%30 == start)
//send notifications
```